# left join not returning all rows from left table?

Tags: sql

I have:

table 1

| key | results |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |

table 2

| key |
| --- |
| A |
| B |

I want to get

| key | result |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | NA |

I try:

```
SELECT        
t1.key, 
t1.results
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 
ON t2.key= t1.key
```

but I get:

| key | result |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |

Am I missing something?

Comment: There is no way that your query returns only 1 row.

Comment: It returns 2 rows, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/TMkEM4Hj), but you should select the data from table t2, not from t1.

Comment: Your query can not return key 'B' because it does not exists in table1: https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2019/31755bdd722148824452cbfd10278af8/ You can use `COALESCE` function for return key exists in on of two tables

Comment: Which dbms  is this ? mysql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `SELECT t1.key` to `SELECT t2.key`. t1 key doesn't exist for all relevant records. you need to select `t2.key`.

```
SELECT t2.key,
       t1.results
FROM   table2 t2
       LEFT JOIN table1 t1 
              ON t2.key= t1.key
```

Comment: that seems to have worked

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T2.KEY,ISNULL(T1.RESULT,'N/A')AS RESULT
FROM TABLE2 AS T2
LEFT JOIN TABL1 AS T1 ON T2.KEY=T1.KEY
```

Please try this one